# How to make imported member link to its documentation with autoapi?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am working on a Python package and I use `sphinx` to build documentation for my package and the `autoapi` [extension](https://sphinx-autoapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to automatically generate API references.

In my package, I have a module named `foo` and inside it a class named `Foo`. The class `Foo` is very central to my package, so I made an import shortcut for it: In `__init__.py` I have the code:

```py
from mypackage.foo import Foo

__all__ = ["Foo", ...]
```

So the end user can simply use `from mypackage import Foo` instead of the more verbose `from mypackage.foo import Foo`. It works well, but it causes a problem with the reference generated by `sphinx-autoapi`. The related configuration of this extension in `conf.py` is:

```py
extensions = [
    "autoapi.extension",
    ...
]

autoapi_dirs = ["../../src"]  # My package location relative to `conf.py`
autoapi_options = [
    "members",
    "show-inheritance",
    "show-module-summary",
    "imported-members",  # This is the problematic option
    "undoc-members",
]
```

Building the documentation with these settings creates an API reference with a page for `mypackage` and subpages for `mypackage.foo` and other modules I have. The `mypackage.foo` page contains all the necessary documentation of the `Foo` class. The problem is that the `mypackage` page **also** contains the same documentation for the `Foo` class. There are several problems with this, but the main ones are that:

- The documentation for the `Foo` class is duplicated in the `mypackage` and `mypackage.foo` pages.
- There are no links between these pages, so just by looking at the documentation, it looks like the `Foo` class exists in both `mypackage` and `mypackage.foo` and it's unclear that `mypackage.Foo` is just a shortcut for `mypackage.foo.Foo`.

If I remove the setting "imported-members" from `autoapi_options`, I get a slightly better result: The documentation for the `Foo` class exists only in the `mypackege.foo` page and in the `mypackage` page, the `Foo` class is shown in the summary of the package (because it's defined in the `__all__` variable, `autoapi` still picks it up. It just doesn't show its documentation since it's an imported member). So, with this setup I see the `Foo` class in the `mypackage` page only in the summary without the details, which makes it clear that this class isn't directly from `mypackage`. The problem is that the `Foo` class is only listed as a member of `mypackage` without any link to its documentation. In other words, the user can't tell where this class comes from or where is its documentation. He can only guess that it's a shortcut for `mypackege.foo.Foo`.

To summarize the problems with both approaches:

- With the "imported-members" option enabled, the documentation of the `Foo` class is shown both in the pages for `mypackage` and `mypackage.foo` which is an unnecessary duplication and it makes it unclear that `mypackage.Foo` is just a shortcut for `mypackage.foo.Foo`.
- With the "imported-members" option disabled, the documentation of the `Foo` class appears only in the page of `mypackage.foo` and in the page of `mypackage`, `Foo` is simply listed as part of the package's contents. The problem is that there is no link from `Foo` in `mypackage` to the full documentation in `mypackage.foo` so the user can understand that `mypackage.Foo` is just a shortcut, but he can't tell where is the actual location and documentation of the `Foo` class.

The solution I'd like is that the documentation of the `Foo` class is only in the `mypackage.foo` page, and in the `mypackage` page, the `Foo` class is still presented in the package's contents but as a link to `mypackage.foo.Foo`. I couldn't figure out how to achieve this with `autoapi`. How can I make imported members link to their documentation in the reference generated by `autoapi`?